# Laravel routes dont show

Tags: php, laravel

I am completely new to laravel, so I think my question is a bit ridiculous.
I tried to create a route in the routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/example', function () {
Return  ('hello');
)};
```

But when I try to see the example page, I receive 404.
I use php artisan serve to load the local host.
I couldn't find a solution relatable to my situation. Still no luck.
Windows version 8.1
Laravel version 8
Also I can't edit

```
Route::get('/', function () {
Return view  ('welcome');
});
```

The changes won't apply
Thank you

Comment: Can you add the request that you're trying? Also, run `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear your cache

Comment: You have a syntax error in your route definition. The closing `}` should be before the closing `)`. Not sure if that's just a typo or is in your `web.php` file. Confirming that, use `php artisan route:list` to check if the route exists.

Comment: The optimize didn't work, I only tried to add this code to web.php

Comment: Dear peppermintology, the original syntax is fine

Comment: The syntax you have originally posted with mismatched brackets is not **fine**. Can you post your entire web.php file?

Answer (score 1):

You can type `php artisan route:list` to see if the route saved or not, if not you can write :

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: No the routes are not saved, the optimize didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct.

```
Route::get('/example', function () {
    Return  view('hello');
});
```

Make your hello.blade.php file add your html code that is your view file.run command php artisan route:clear.